# How to disable the shadow on html css

Tags: html, css

I am making a project without using bootstrap and I designed a input like this.https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHxFp.png

I want to use the border-radius but I want to disable the shadows.

How could I disable it without using border-radius: none;

Comment: Hi do you have the CSS code for this box?

Comment: Yes It's only {width: 30vw;
    height: 5vh;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
}

Comment: How about the HTML also?

Comment: <input class = "tokenneed" placeholder = "토큰을 입력해주세요" type = "text">
It's inside a form but there is no css on the form

Comment: Ok. please see my answer.

Comment: No problem.  Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to have border radius, you can add an actual border to the box and it will appear without the shadow.  like this:

```css
.tokenneed {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 5vh;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input class = "tokenneed" placeholder = "토큰을 입력해주세요" type = "text">
```